# ELK Stack, logstash.log size increasing every second but system still working

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, dns, logstash, elastic-stack

I have an ELK Stack running on AWS, overall system is as follows, App servers (4 at the moment) forwards logs to Logstash-Shipper using Logstash-Forwarder on each EC2 instance, Logstash-Shipper ships them logs onto Kafka/Zookeeper with topic name "Elk-Stack". Logstash-Indexer receives the logs from the topic "Elk-Stack", filters that log data and output to Elasticsearch. I have a Loadbalancer on a cluster of 2 Elasticsearch EC2 instances, and Kibana is used to visualize that log data to do some analysis.

My Logstash-Indexer Config file for input, filter and output are as follows.

**01-log-inout.conf**

```
input {
  kafka {
        zk_connect => "KAFKA-IP-HERE:2181"
        topic_id => "ELK-Stack"
  }
}
```

**20-sys_app1.conf**

```
filter {
      grok {
            match => {
              "message" => "%{IP:Host} \(%{IP:ClientIP}, %{IP:HostIP}\) - - \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"%{GREEDYDATA:MessageNotParsed}\""
            }
        }

        date {
            locale => "en"
            timezone => "UTC"
            match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
            target => "@timestamp"
        }
        mutate {
            add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
        }
     geoip {
        source => "ClientIP"
        target => "geoip"
        database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
    }
    mutate {
        convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
    }

}
```

**99-output-to-es.conf**

```
output { 
    elasticsearch { 
           host => "DNS-NameOfLoadBalancer-eb.amazonaws.com"
           protocol => http 
    }
}
```

When I check the Logstash-Indexer log file I see 3 different logstash `".log", ".stdout" and ".err"`. The .err and .stdout seem to not change but the logstash.log is increasing by the second. I ran `ls -ltr /var/log/logstash/`.

[image]

When I check this file I see a lot of data but not sure what it means, does anyone have an idea why this is happening. Here is some of the output I tried to get as must of one single lump cause it seem to repeat.

```
{:timestamp=>"2015-11-26T18:08:49.748000+0000", :message=>"Failed to flush outgoing items", :outgoing_count=>1, :exception=>"Manticore::ClientProto
colException", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.4.4-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:35:in `initialize'", "org/jr
uby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.4.4-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:70:in `call'", "/opt/l
ogstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.4.4-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:245:in `call_once'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gem
s/manticore-0.4.4-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:148:in `code'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/ela
sticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:71:in `perform_request'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jr
uby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:191:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/j
ruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:54:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendo
r/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:119:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundl
e/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:87:in `bulk'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash
-output-elasticsearch-1.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/protocol.rb:104:in `bulk'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstas
h-output-elasticsearch-1.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:542:in `submit'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-outp
ut-elasticsearch-1.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:541:in `submit'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-ela
sticsearch-1.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:566:in `flush'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsea
rch-1.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:565:in `flush'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.21/lib/stud/buffer.rb:21
9:in `buffer_flush'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.21/lib/stud/buffer.rb:216:in `
buffer_flush'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.21/lib/stud/buffer.rb:159:in `buffer_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/j
ruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-1.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:531:in `receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/
1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:88:in `handle'", "(eval):22:in `output_func'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.
9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.5-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:244:in `outputworker'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.5-ja
va/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:166:in `start_outputs'"], :level=>:warn}
{:timestamp=>"2015-11-26T18:08:50.283000+0000", :message=>["INFLIGHT_EVENTS_REPORT", "2015-11-26T18:08:50Z", {"input_to_filter"=>1, "filter_to_outp
ut"=>1, "outputs"=>[]}], :level=>:warn}
{:timestamp=>"2015-11-26T18:08:50.478000+0000", :message=>["INFLIGHT_EVENTS_REPORT", "2015-11-26T18:08:50Z", {"input_to_filter"=>20, "filter_to_out
put"=>20, "outputs"=>[]}], :level=>:warn}
{:timestamp=>"2015-11-26T18:08:50.753000+0000", :message=>"Got error to send bulk of actions: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP respon
se", :level=>:error}

{:timestamp=>"2015-11-26T18:08:50.753000+0000", :message=>"Failed to flush outgoing items", :outgoing_count=>1, :exception=>"Manticore::ClientProto
    colException", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.4.4-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:35:in `initialize'", "org/jr
    uby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.4.4-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:70:in `call'", "/opt/l
    ogstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.4.4-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:245:in `call_once'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gem
    s/manticore-0.4.4-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:148:in `code'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/ela
    sticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:71:in `perform_request'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jr
    uby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:191:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:54:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:119:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:87:in `bulk'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-1.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/protocol.rb:104:in `bulk'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-1.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:542:in `submit'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-1.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:541:in `submit'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-1.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:566:in `flush'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-1.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:565:in `flush'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.21/lib/stud/buffer.rb:219:in `buffer_flush'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.21/lib/stud/buffer.rb:216:in `buffer_flush'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.21/lib/stud/buffer.rb:159:in `buffer_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-1.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:531:in `receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:88:in `handle'", "(eval):22:in `output_func'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.5-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:244:in `outputworker'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.5-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:166:in `start_outputs'"], :level=>:warn}
    {:timestamp=>"2015-11-26T18:08:51.758000+0000", :message=>"Got error to send bulk of actions: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response", :level=>:error}
```

Why is this happening? What does it mean? I am very confused here because I can see the log data in Elasticsearch using the (Head plugin) using the URL of the Loadbalancer (DNS NAME) `"http://DNS-NameOfLoadBalancer-eb.amazonaws.com:9200/_plugin/head` and I can view the data and quesry it in Kibana in the discovery tab.

Here is a visual representation of my system.

[image]

Your help in trying to solve this mystery will be greatly appreciated.

G

Comment: Your log entry says, "Failed to flush outgoing items" and "Got error to send bulk of actions: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response".  Check your elasticsearch logs.  Also, I believe that turning up debugging in logstash will show you the message being sent (which you could replay manually) and possibly the real error message returned by elasticsearch.

Comment: Hi @Alain Collins thanks for taken the time to try help, how can I turn up debugging in logstash as you suggest so I could see the message been sent and real error message from elasticsearch.

Comment: logstash takes either a "--verbose" or "--debug" parameter.  Check your startup script to see where these should be set.

Comment: Still no joy, and no other help.